# How do I remove MacPorts on an "unsupported OS" i.e. El Capitan Public beta?

Tags: macos, macports, osx-elcapitan

The MacPorts installation that I had on Yosemite doesn't work on the El Capitan since it isn't supported yet. I want to remove the Port installation here but I'm not able to run any of the Port commands. Does anyone have an idea how to clean it up?

On running any port command, I get the following error:

```
Error: Current platform "darwin 15" does not match expected platform "darwin 14"
Error: If you upgraded your OS, please follow the migration instructions: https://trac.macports.org/wiki/Migration
OS platform mismatch
    while executing
"mportinit ui_options global_options global_variations"
Error: /opt/local/bin/port: Failed to initialize MacPorts, OS platform mismatch
```

Comment: Here is uninstall guide - https://guide.macports.org/chunked/installing.macports.uninstalling.html

Comment: Thanks for the response. I already checked that out. The problem is that I cannot run the port command itself due to being on the beta. The installation expects darwin 14 (yosemite) whereas the installed OS is darwin 15 (i.e. el capitan)

Comment: I think the second command (sudo rm -rf \  /opt/local \ etc.) should be enough to clean all files even when port is not functioning

Comment: The second command is *not* always enough, because MacPorts occasionally installs files outside of `/opt/local`. The correct course of action is re-installing MacPorts from source as explained in https://guide.macports.org/#installing.macports.source.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I tried compiling from source. I get the error: "Foundation library not found" which from the forums seems to a error without a solution, particularly since I do have the foundation libraries (and Xcode and the dev tools).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I just went ahead and manually removed the files (using rm):

```
sudo rm -rf /opt/local \
    /Applications/DarwinPorts \
    /Applications/MacPorts \
    /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.* \
    /Library/Receipts/DarwinPorts*.pkg \
    /Library/Receipts/MacPorts*.pkg \
    /Library/StartupItems/DarwinPortsStartup \
    /Library/Tcl/darwinports1.0 \
    /Library/Tcl/macports1.0 \
    ~/.macports
```

It didn't seem to leave any leftovers or break anything.

One thing to note however is that mactex seems to have been installed in the same directory so that got removed as well. I didn't realize that I had that in the same directory. If you're going to repeat the same steps, keep this in mind.

Comment: so mactex affects what all ? how can we reinstall that ?

Comment: @bicepjai: Mactext is just a text editor he installed using Macports. You can reinstall later using port again or brew or something else.

Comment: Not mactext, mactex. It's a latex package for OSX. You might not have it installed. If you don't know what it is, you probably don't have it.

Answer (score 24):

This solution worked for me, without remove it:

- xcode-select --install
- xcodebuild -license
- wget https://distfiles.macports.org/MacPorts/MacPorts-2.3.3.tar.bz2
- tar xzvf MacPorts-2.3.3.tar.bz2
- cd MacPorts-2.3.3
- ./configure && make && sudo make install
- cd ../
- rm -rf MacPorts-2.3.3*

[Source](https://www.macports.org/install.php)

Comment: Thank you! Didn't know the source is compatible with El Capitan, but the installer is not.

Comment: Does the sudo make install work on El Capitan? I thought writes to system folders were disabled by default. Or did you disable that? 

Thanks!

Comment: A newer version of MacPorts is available 2.5.4 for MacOS 10.4. https://www.macports.org/install.php

Answer (score 7):

What I did successfully on my El Capitan:

1. xcode-select --install
2. xcodebuild -license
3. Reinstall MacPorts by using the correct *.pkg matching your OSX from https://www.macports.org/install.php
4. done.

Comment: Works for me. There was package mismatch.

Answer (score 1):

wget is fetching a bz2 file but unzip instructions are for gz.
Try the following instead

```
tar xjvf MacPorts-2.3.3.tar.bz2
```

The rest worked fine on El Capitan.

Thanks.

Comment: A newer version of MacPorts is available 2.5.4 for MacOS 10.4. macports.org/install.php