# CGContextSaveGState error with Xcode 7 + React Native

Tags: xcode, react-native

I just upgrade to xCode 7 and I started to generate a simple "Hello world" react native application. However, there are the following error messages. Did someone know the reason and solution?

> Sep 20 00:44:02  WeatherApp[10922] : CGContextSaveGState:
>   invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set
>   CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable. Sep 20 00:44:02 
>   WeatherApp[10922] : CGContextTranslateCTM: invalid context 0x0.
>   If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE
>   environmental variable. Sep 20 00:44:02  WeatherApp[10922] :
>   CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the
>   backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental
>   variable. 2015-09-20 00:44:14.330
>   [info][tid:com.facebook.React.JavaScript] 'Running application
>   "WeatherApp" with appParams: {"rootTag":1,"initialProps":{}}. **DEV**
>   === true, development-level warning are ON, performance optimizations are OFF' 2015-09-20 00:46:14.387
>   [warn][tid:com.facebook.React.JavaScript] 'devtools socket closed'

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug with iOS 9.0 and the status bar API.

On iOS you can specify with whether the status bar's color should be controlled by UIViewController's `preferredStatusBarStyle` or by calling `-[UIApplication setStatusBarStyle:]`. Since React Native doesn't use view controllers, it uses the latter style of controlling the status bar color. This causes iOS 9.0 to print:

```
CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace,
please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
```

In practice the app works fine.

Comment: [might help](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31887785/3577656) and here is apple [thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/13683) in which apple staff said,this warning can be avoided for now and it is a known isssue.

Answer (score -1):

2 options:

If watchman is installed via brew, just do brew update && brew upgrade watchman

Otherwise, uninstall macports (by this guide if you're on El Capitan: [How do I remove MacPorts on an "unsupported OS" i.e. El Capitan Public beta?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31483432/how-do-i-remove-macports-on-an-unsupported-os-i-e-el-capitan-public-beta)) and reinstall watchman via brew

More info on https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1875