# Error: Current platform "darwin 15" does not match expected platform "darwin 14

Tags: macos, macports

I just upgraded my OS X from 10.10.5 to OS X El Capitan 10.11.

I tried to update my mac ports to version 2.3.3 ...

Mac ports is getting this error:

```
$ sudo port selfupdate
Error: Current platform "darwin 15" does not match expected platform "darwin 14

$ port -qv installed > myports.txt
Error: Current platform "darwin 15" does not match expected platform "darwin 14"
Error: If you upgraded your OS, please follow the migration instructions: https://trac.macports.org/wiki/Migration
Error: /opt/local/bin/port: Failed to initialize MacPorts, OS platform mismatch
```

Any ideas?

I tried following these porting instructions:

https://www.ghostwheel.com/merlin/Personal/notes/2015/09/14/installing-macports-on-os-x-10-11-el-capitan/

but the 'make' of macport 2.3.3 failed:

...

```
ld: warning: ignoring file ../cregistry/cregistry.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): ../cregistry/cregistry.a
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_reg_all_open_entries", referenced from:
      _registry_tcl_detach in registry.o
  "_reg_all_open_files", referenced from:
      _registry_tcl_detach in registry.o
  "_reg_attach", referenced from:
      _registry_open in registry.o
  "_reg_close", referenced from:
      _delete_reg in registry.o
  "_reg_commit", referenced from:
      _registry_read in registry.o
      _registry_write in registry.o
  "_reg_del_metadata", referenced from:
      _metadata_cmd in registry.o
  "_reg_detach", referenced from:
      _registry_tcl_detach in registry.o
  "_reg_entry_activate", referenced from:
      _entry_obj_activate in entryobj.o
  "_reg_entry_addgroup", referenced from:
      _entry_obj_add_portgroup in entryobj.o
  "_reg_entry_create", referenced from:
      _entry_create in entry.o
  "_reg_entry_deactivate", referenced from:
      _filemap_cmds in entryobj.o
  "_reg_entry_delete", referenced from:
      _entry_delete in entry.o
  "_reg_entry_dependencies", referenced from:
      _entry_obj_dependencies in entryobj.o
  "_reg_entry_dependents", referenced from:
      _entry_obj_dependents in entryobj.o
  "_reg_entry_depends", referenced from:
      _entry_obj_depends in entryobj.o
  "_reg_entry_files", referenced from:
      _entry_obj_files in entryobj.o
  "_reg_entry_free", referenced from:
      _registry_write in registry.o
      _delete_entry_list in registry.o
      _entry_delete in entry.o
  "_reg_entry_getgroups", referenced from:
      _entry_obj_get_portgroups in entryobj.o
  "_reg_entry_imaged", referenced from:
      _entry_imaged in entry.o
  "_reg_entry_imagefiles", referenced from:
      _entry_obj_imagefiles in entryobj.o
  "_reg_entry_installed", referenced from:
      _entry_installed in entry.o
  "_reg_entry_map", referenced from:
      _filemap_cmds in entryobj.o
  "_reg_entry_open", referenced from:
      _entry_open in entry.o
  "_reg_entry_owner", referenced from:
      _entry_owner in entry.o
  "_reg_entry_propget", referenced from:
      _entry_obj_prop in entryobj.o
  "_reg_entry_propset", referenced from:
      _entry_obj_prop in entryobj.o
  "_reg_entry_search", referenced from:
      _entry_search in entry.o
  "_reg_entry_unmap", referenced from:
      _filemap_cmds in entryobj.o
  "_reg_error_destruct", referenced from:
      _registry_failed in registry.o
      _registry_tcl_detach in registry.o
      _registry_for in registry.o
      _delete_reg in registry.o
      _metadata_cmd in registry.o
      _registry_open in registry.o
      _registry_close in registry.o
      ...
  "_reg_file_open", referenced from:
      _file_open in file.o
  "_reg_file_propget", referenced from:
      _file_obj_prop in fileobj.o
  "_reg_file_propset", referenced from:
      _file_obj_prop in fileobj.o
  "_reg_file_search", referenced from:
      _file_search in file.o
  "_reg_get_metadata", referenced from:
      _metadata_cmd in registry.o
  "_reg_open", referenced from:
      _registry_for in registry.o
  "_reg_portgroup_open", referenced from:
      _portgroup_open in portgroup.o
  "_reg_portgroup_propget", referenced from:
      _portgroup_obj_prop in portgroupobj.o
  "_reg_portgroup_propset", referenced from:
      _portgroup_obj_prop in portgroupobj.o
  "_reg_portgroup_search", referenced from:
      _portgroup_search in portgroup.o
  "_reg_rollback", referenced from:
      _registry_read in registry.o
      _registry_write in registry.o
  "_reg_set_metadata", referenced from:
      _metadata_cmd in registry.o
  "_reg_start_read", referenced from:
      _registry_read in registry.o
  "_reg_start_write", referenced from:
      _registry_write in registry.o
  "_reg_vacuum", referenced from:
      _delete_reg in registry.o
      _registry_close in registry.o
  "_registry_err_not_found", referenced from:
      _metadata_cmd in registry.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [registry.dylib] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Make of 2.3.4 also failed:

```
lndefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_reg_all_open_entries", referenced from:
      _registry_tcl_detach in registry.o
  "_reg_all_open_files", referenced from:
      _registry_tcl_detach in registry.o
  "_reg_attach", referenced from:
      _registry_open in registry.o
  "_reg_close", referenced from:
      _delete_reg in registry.o
  "_reg_commit", referenced from:
      _registry_read in registry.o
      _registry_write in registry.o
  "_reg_del_metadata", referenced from:
      _metadata_cmd in registry.o
  "_reg_detach", referenced from:
      _registry_tcl_detach in registry.o
  "_reg_entry_activate", referenced from:
      _entry_obj_activate in entryobj.o
  "_reg_entry_addgroup", referenced from:
      _entry_obj_add_portgroup in entryobj.o
  "_reg_entry_create", referenced from:
      _entry_create in entry.o
  "_reg_entry_deactivate", referenced from:
      _filemap_cmds in entryobj.o
  "_reg_entry_delete", referenced from:
      _entry_delete in entry.o
  "_reg_entry_dependencies", referenced from:
      _entry_obj_dependencies in entryobj.o
  "_reg_entry_dependents", referenced from:
      _entry_obj_dependents in entryobj.o
  "_reg_entry_depends", referenced from:
      _entry_obj_depends in entryobj.o
  "_reg_entry_files", referenced from:
      _entry_obj_files in entryobj.o
  "_reg_entry_free", referenced from:
      _registry_write in registry.o
      _delete_entry_list in registry.o
      _entry_delete in entry.o
  "_reg_entry_getgroups", referenced from:
      _entry_obj_get_portgroups in entryobj.o
  "_reg_entry_imaged", referenced from:
      _entry_imaged in entry.o
  "_reg_entry_imagefiles", referenced from:
      _entry_obj_imagefiles in entryobj.o
  "_reg_entry_installed", referenced from:
      _entry_installed in entry.o
  "_reg_entry_map", referenced from:
      _filemap_cmds in entryobj.o
  "_reg_entry_open", referenced from:
      _entry_open in entry.o
  "_reg_entry_owner", referenced from:
      _entry_owner in entry.o
  "_reg_entry_propget", referenced from:
      _entry_obj_prop in entryobj.o
  "_reg_entry_propset", referenced from:
      _entry_obj_prop in entryobj.o
  "_reg_entry_search", referenced from:
      _entry_search in entry.o
  "_reg_entry_unmap", referenced from:
      _filemap_cmds in entryobj.o
  "_reg_error_destruct", referenced from:
      _registry_failed in registry.o
      _registry_tcl_detach in registry.o
      _registry_for in registry.o
      _delete_reg in registry.o
      _metadata_cmd in registry.o
      _registry_open in registry.o
      _registry_close in registry.o
      ...
  "_reg_file_open", referenced from:
      _file_open in file.o
  "_reg_file_propget", referenced from:
      _file_obj_prop in fileobj.o
  "_reg_file_propset", referenced from:
      _file_obj_prop in fileobj.o
  "_reg_file_search", referenced from:
      _file_search in file.o
  "_reg_get_metadata", referenced from:
      _metadata_cmd in registry.o
  "_reg_open", referenced from:
      _registry_for in registry.o
  "_reg_portgroup_open", referenced from:
      _portgroup_open in portgroup.o
  "_reg_portgroup_propget", referenced from:
      _portgroup_obj_prop in portgroupobj.o
  "_reg_portgroup_propset", referenced from:
      _portgroup_obj_prop in portgroupobj.o
  "_reg_portgroup_search", referenced from:
      _portgroup_search in portgroup.o
  "_reg_rollback", referenced from:
      _registry_read in registry.o
      _registry_write in registry.o
  "_reg_set_metadata", referenced from:
      _metadata_cmd in registry.o
  "_reg_start_read", referenced from:
      _registry_read in registry.o
  "_reg_start_write", referenced from:
      _registry_write in registry.o
  "_reg_vacuum", referenced from:
      _delete_reg in registry.o
      _registry_close in registry.o
  "_registry_err_not_found", referenced from:
      _metadata_cmd in registry.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [registry.dylib] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

There is no 2.3.4 .pkg on the mac port site.

https://distfiles.macports.org/MacPorts/

Answer (score 5):

> Error: If you upgraded your OS, please follow the migration instructions: https://trac.macports.org/wiki/Migration

EDIT: The easiest is to just download the MacPorts 2.3.4 installer for El Capitan from the MacPorts site.

Comment: I tried those instruction.  Step 3. failed (See above).  Building Macports 2.3.4 failed.  Trying MacPorts 2.3.4 installer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31483432/how-do-i-remove-macports-on-an-unsupported-os-i-e-el-capitan-public-beta  ld: warning: ignoring file ../cregistry/cregistry.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): ../cregistry/cregistry.a

Comment: There is no mac port 2.3.4 package installer listed here: https://distfiles.macports.org/MacPorts/

Comment: Follow the migration link above, then click on [install the base MacPorts system](https://www.macports.org/install.php) and then on [OS X 10.11 El Capitan](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/macports/MacPorts/2.3.4/MacPorts-2.3.4-10.11-ElCapitan.pkg)

Answer (score 3):

m7thon's solution worked for me on both my iMac (Late 2013) and MacbookPro (Early 2015). Follow the  link provided by m7thon:

[MacPort Migration Instructions -->](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/Migration) https://trac.macports.org/wiki/Migration.

After installing the new version of MacPorts for El Capitan, follow the instructions to 1) compile a list of your installed ports (they weren't deleted when you upgraded to El Capitan), 2) delete them, and 3) reinstall them. Make sure you install Xcode command line tools prior to steps 1 thru 3:

```
xcode-select --install
```

Depending on how many ports you have installed, Step 3 can take a few hours, so make sure you are connected to a power source. For example, it takes the better part of an hour for MacPorts to build the gcc library.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I was able to build and run port 2.3.4 from github.
For some reason,

```
$./configure
$ make
```

got an linker error.
I resolved the linker error by doing a make in the ./src/cregistry subdirectory

```
$ cd src/cregistry
$ make
$ cd ../..
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

After that port selfupdate and  sudo port upgrade outdated worked.

Comment: Erm, AFAIK, MacPorts is not even officially hosted on GitHub. Could it be that you have been using some unofficial MacPorts fork?

Comment: You're correct it wasn't github.  It was here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/macports/files/MacPorts/2.3.4/

Answer (score 0):

MacPorts has released their official El Capitan installer:
https://www.macports.org/install.php